# The [filament] is burning out

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I was trying to ask a question about the Filament rendering system. It occurred to me that there were two more specific tags regarding "filament": [laravel-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-filament) and [google-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-filament), which refer to different libraries. Looking at the criteria for burnination:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is definitely ambigious, as I said before: it describes potentially two different libraries.

- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Technically, no. Filament has nothing to do with programming. But it also refers to two libraries, as Shog9 put it: "Stack Overflow doesn't need a kittens tag, at least not until someone releases a hot new framework and names it 'Kittens'" So yes, it is on topic.

- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. If you are using the correct tags for your library ([google-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-filament)/[laravel-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-filament)), then [filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filament) adds nothing.

- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. If you  have [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) it refers to one library, and if you have [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) it refers to another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep.  This tag's entirely redundant.

The following three questions have been retagged to [google-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-filament):

- [Filament image viewer on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75821766/filament-image-viewer-on-android)
- [SurfaceView background, how to make surfaceview transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261001/surfaceview-background-how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent)
- [How to let the emissive property work in Sceneform ？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74859872/how-to-let-the-emissive-property-work-in-sceneform)

This question tagged [google-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-filament) has had the [filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filament) tag removed:

- [Why is my Filament program failing to build with an error from within Filament?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76231875/why-is-my-filament-program-failing-to-build-with-an-error-from-within-filament)

I also added the [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) tag to several [filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filament) questions that had other Laravel-related tags.  At this point, all 32 remaining questions tagged [filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filament) were also tagged [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel).

I then merged [filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filament) into [laravel-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-filament) without creating a synonym, retagging those 32 questions and adding [laravel-filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-filament) to the 15 of them that did not already have it.